# Como resolver InvalidFormatException em arquivo xls gerado por jett?

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, relatório, xls, apache-poi

Tenho um metodo de gerar relatorio feito com jett:

```
Map<String, Object> beans = new HashMap<String, Object>();

beans.put("fichasTecnicasMateriaPrimaResumo", fichasTecnicasMateriaPrimaResumo);

try {

    InputStream inPath = ProdutoManagedBean.class.getResourceAsStream("/template.xls");

    ExcelTransformer transformer = new ExcelTransformer();
    transformer.transform(inPath, beans);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

estou tendo uma InvalidFormatException no transformer.transfom(...):

```
22:44:37,803 ERROR [stderr] (default task-28) org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

quando mudo a extensão do arquivo para .ods a exception muda:

```
12:46:34,703 ERROR [stderr] (default task-57) java.util.zip.ZipException: unexpected EOF
```

Gerei os arquivos pelo microsoft office e pelo libreoffice e ambos deram erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que na verdade o xls esta sendo corrompido pelo maven...quando eu tento abrir o arquivo que esta na pasta de deploy do wildfly ele ja vem corrompido...busquei algumas soluções para resolver esse problema de corrupção de dados mas ainda não achei nada que funcionasse, mas pelo menos já sei qual é o verdadeiro erro.